# Android 8.0 DownloadManager won't open file after opening it from the notification center

Tags: android, apk

I've been trying to download an .apk file from my server using `DownloadManager`.

For some reason Android 8.0 refuses to open the file.

After downloading the .apk file; clicking the notification center doesn't do anything. No errors, no tracebacks, no exceptions.

1. Mimetype : `application/vnd.android.package-archive`
2. File Type : `APK`

This works on Android OS 6.0 : the procedure is as expected.

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.